# Check if the JValue is an Array in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Json string

```
string s =  @"{""A"": [""AB""]}"
```

I want to check if the `JValue` is an Array or not. My jsonstring can have an array or can also be

```
string s =  @"{""A"": ""A[B""}"
```

The only way that i can find is `JObject.Parse(s)["A"].Contains("[")`. But this is not always true as my string itself can have "[" or "]" . Please suggest a solution in C#

Comment: Your json string doesn't look valid. And your code block does not look valid c# code. Can you share original json?

Comment: @kordiseps - updated my string

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would let the JSON parser deduce that for you. If you're using Newtonsoft, then it could look like this:

```
var str0 = @"{""A"": [""AB""]}";
var str1 = @"{""A"": ""A[B""}";
var o0 = JObject.Parse(str0);
var o1 = JObject.Parse(str1);
Console.WriteLine("o0.A type: " + o0["A"].Type);
Console.WriteLine("o1.A type: " + o1["A"].Type);
```

The output would be:

```
o0.A type: Array
o1.A type: String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SelectToken method using jsonPath in Newtonsoft. like this:

```
            string s1 = @"{""A"": [""AB""]}";
            string s2 = @"{""A"": ""A[B""}";
            var parseS1 = JToken.Parse(s1);
            var parseS2 = JToken.Parse(s2);
            Console.WriteLine(parseS1.SelectToken("A").Type);
            Console.WriteLine(parseS2.SelectToken("A").Type);
```